# Trying to traverse an object in php breaking down

Tags: php, oop, object, loops, foreach

Hi I have an object that is being called and some of those objects are containing other objects, I am using foreach to go through each property to put it into a new array and using an if statement inside the foreach to see if the property contains another object and if it does using another foreach to get the properties of the object within the the object property.

The problem is that once I get 2 levels deep it just falls apart i know that there is an object inside by doing an is_object test which returns true but when i try to travesere its properties its just not getting any info out of it.

```
private static function prepare_page($output_object) {
    foreach ($output_object as $object) {

    if (is_a($object, "subjects")) {
        $return_object["{{::SUBJECT::}}"] = $object->name;
    }

    if (is_a($object, "posts")) {
        $return_object["{{::POST::}}"] = $object->name;

        foreach ($object as $atribute => $value) {

            if (is_object($value) || is_array($value)) {

                foreach ($object as $property => $val) {

                    if (is_object($val)) {

                        echo "It's an object inside an object";
                            dump($val);
                            //works till here lets me know its an object and shows the $val with its contents (objects)

                            foreach ($val as $ob => $at) {
                                //breaks down here if i dump the $ob or $at it doesn't do anything      
                                if (!is_object($at)) {
                                    $return_object["{{::>>".strtoupper($ob)."::}}"] = $at;
                                } else {
                                    //  repeat process
                                }
                            }
                    } else {
                        $return_object["{{::==".strtoupper($property)."::}}"] = $val;
                    }

                }
            } else {
                if (!is_object($value) && !is_array($value)) {
                    $return_object["{{::".strtoupper($atribute)."::}}"] = $value;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
return $return_object;
}
```

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is it possible to make it point to a method? Like so: `$object->method`. Can maybe also be used within a `foreach` output, like so: `$value->attribute`. IMO a nested `foreach` is a bad idea, when you can simply point to the object or method you need. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I may be wrong, but i believe the problem here is how you're handling the object.

You see, is_object() returns true if the object is an object, not an array. The foreach loop works with arrays, but not with objects.

In order to get it to work, you probably must first convert your object into an array.

Why don't you try and do this:

Before

```
foreach ($val as $ob => $at) {
```

Call a function to convert it into an array, like this:

```
$val = object_to_array($val);
foreach ($val as $ob => $at) {
```

And then declare that function somewhere in your code, outside all loop structures. The function goes above:

```
function object_to_array($object) {
    $array = array();
    if (is_object($object)) {
        $array = get_object_vars($object);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Hope I was able to help! =)

Comment: Well now that i gave it a second thought, maybe foreach does work with objects, i don't know... you may as well apply the function right at the beggining, to convert the whole object into an array, which would probably make it easier to work with.

Comment: foreach dos work with objects - hence the first iteration of the object inside the function. but i did give you a vote on your answer at least for trying i have check this site for other similar questions with no luck and this has been bugging me for almost 2 days now but i guess i will continue trying and keep you posted once i do figure it out